# Calling Microsoft Graph API from Azure Function to retrieve user's Contacts

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions

I cannot find a good working sample that calls the Graph API and retrieves the user's contacts from within an Azure Function. Part of the issue is a lack of documentation and samples as this seems new-ish. Is this even possible? I am trying to create a function that can take a phone number and check against the user's contacts to see if the contact exists. So far, the only way I can achieve authentication is to use Postman to retrieve a token manually. That token didn't even work to retrieve the contacts. I know I am doing something wrong but I think what I really need is the big picture. I'm missing something. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [auth token binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-microsoft-graph#auth-token) may help at least with the act of getting the token. In this case, if it's on behalf of the user invoking the function, you'll want to use the `identity: userFromRequest` setup. Keep in mind that for debugging, you'd still have to acquire a user token for the app and attach that to calls to your function, but you can use the function app's `/.auth/login/aad` and `/.auth/me` endpoints for that.

Make sure that your application registration has the **Contacts.Read** permission. This is required for the [contacts API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/contact_delta).Today, the UX for App Service Authentication / Authorization today links to the existing permissions UX, which unfortunately uses different names for things. I'd recommend navigating directly to the AAD section of the portal and selecting *App registrations (Preview)*. Find your app registration there (defaults to same as your app name), and browse through the API permissions there. That way the right names show up and will match the Graph docs.

Comment: I will give this a try and report back. There are so many outdated tutorials and none of which are exactly what I am trying to accomplish. The few that are close are off base in one way or another. I am going to try to get auth working first. You state that for testing I have to get the token. What happens in production? Is that somehow handled? If so, why can't I do the same thing during testing? Thanks for helping me clear this issue in my mind!!

Comment: I was able to get this working by making explicit calls to the API to get a token and then programmatically use that token to retrieve results from the Graph. Thanks for your assistance!